# maximum number of smaller circle possible from a big circle

Tags: circles

a big circle has radius 5 cm is cut down into smaller circles of radius 1 cm .How many maximum number of smaller circle possible? How it is calculated?

Comment: What did you try to solve this problem?

Comment: The answer should be $18$, but I wouldn't know how to prove formally it is the best possible packing.

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud  the short trick is 0.83*R2/r2-1.9 but i want to know the concept behind this formula...

Comment: @Daniel Robert-Nicoud and anil: There is a better solution

Comment: @anil. Where did you find this short trick ?

Comment: @Henry OOps, I miscounted. I meant exactly your solution.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici  somewhere on the internet..I do not remember exactly....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Erich Friedman's Packing Center suggests](https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/cirincir/) that F. Fodor proved in 1999 that $19$ unit circles fit in a circle of radius $1 + \sqrt2 + \sqrt6 =4.863\ldots$, while Goldberg found in 1971 that $20$ unit circles could fit in a circle of radius $5.122\ldots$.

So the answer seems to be $19$.

[image: Nineteen circles packed in a circle]

Comment: is there any generalized  concept...suppose if i want to fit 100 same sized circle in a big circle..then what will be the radius of big circle..?????

Comment: There will be approximations, but there does not seem to be a general rule. It may be worth reading: Graham RL, Lubachevsky BD, Nurmela KJ,Ostergard PRJ. Dense packings of congruent circles in a circle. Discrete Math 1998;181:139–154. http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~ronspubs/98_01_circles.pdf